# German Tax Implications for a US Citizen/German Spouse who Maintain a Part-time Residence in Germany

Tags: usa, germany

I am a US citizen with a German citizen spouse. We have resided in the U.S. for the past 25 years with my wife having a US Green Card. I'm considering purchasing a second home in Germany and residing there part-time each year during our retirement. I expect that our primary residence (over 50% of the time) will remain in the U.S.

What are the tax implications for pension income, IRA, 401K, and other investments for the German government?